# When are index level tokenizers/tokenFilters/CharFilters used?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

When are the index level tokenizers/tokenFilters/CharFilters used if each of the fields in the index definition already has a customer analayzer for both indexing & searching?

Ex:

```
Index indexDefiniton = new Index()
            {
                Name = myIndexName,
                Fields = FieldBuilder.BuildForType<AzureIndexDocument>(),
                Analyzers = new[]
                {
                    new CustomAnalyzer()
                    {
                        Name = indexConstants.DefaultIndexAnalyzerName,
                        CharFilters = new[] { 
                            CharFilterName.Create(indexConstants.SlashFilterName),
                            CharFilterName.Create(indexConstants.DashFilterName)                          
                        },
                        Tokenizer = TokenizerName.Whitespace,
                        TokenFilters = new[] { TokenFilterName.Lowercase},
                    },
                    new CustomAnalyzer()
                    {
                        Name = indexConstants.PrefixAnalyzerName,
                        Tokenizer = TokenizerName.Whitespace,
                        TokenFilters = new[] { TokenFilterName.Lowercase,
                                                TokenFilterName.Stopwords,
                                            },
                    },
                    new CustomAnalyzer()
                    {
                        Name = indexConstants.SearchTermAnalyzerName,
                        Tokenizer = TokenizerName.Whitespace,
                        TokenFilters = new[] { TokenFilterName.Lowercase }
                    },
                    new CustomAnalyzer()
                    {
                        Name = indexConstants.KeywordIndexAnalyzer,
                        Tokenizer = TokenizerName.Keyword,
                        TokenFilters = new[] { TokenFilterName.Lowercase , TokenFilterName.Trim }
                    }
                },

                TokenFilters = new List<TokenFilter>
                {
                    new EdgeNGramTokenFilterV2
                    {
                        Name = indexConstants.PrefixCreatingTokenFilterName, MinGram = 1, MaxGram = 50
                    },
                    new WordDelimiterTokenFilter
                    {
                        Name = indexConstants.CatenateNumberFilterTokenFilterName ,
                        CatenateNumbers = true,
                        CatenateWords = true,
                        CatenateAll = true ,
                        PreserveOriginal = true
                    }
                },

                CharFilters = new List<CharFilter>
                {
                    new PatternReplaceCharFilter(indexConstants.SlashFilterName, s_Slash, s_Space),
                    new PatternReplaceCharFilter(indexConstants.DashFilterName, s_Dash, s_Space),
                    new PatternReplaceCharFilter(indexConstants.UnderScoreFilterName, s_UnderScore, s_Space),
                    new PatternReplaceCharFilter(indexConstants.RoundBracketOpeningFilterName, s_RoundBracketOpening, s_Space),
                    new PatternReplaceCharFilter(indexConstants.RoundBracketClosingFilterName, s_RoundBracketClosing, s_Space)
                },
};
```

Let's say all of the fields declared in the index definition either use keyword/prefix/default analyzer as declared above for indexing and searchAnalayzer for searching. Then when will the TokenFilter (EdgeNGramTokenFilterV2, WorddelimitTokenFilter), CharFilters declared as part of the index used here ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly refer to the custom analyzers in the field where you want them to be used (either by setting the "analyzer" property on that field, or the "indexAnalyzer" and "searchAnalyzer", to the name of the custom analyzer you want to use). If you simply create a custom analyzer but don't actually use it in any field, it will not be used.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ramero-MSFT. Yes, I am assigning the custom analyzer to the fields as needed. The question I have is when will the TokenFilter (EdgeNGramTokenFilterV2, WorddelimitTokenFilter), CharFilters declared as part of the index used here?

Comment: The custom token filters and char filters need to be referenced in your custom analyzer. They will be part of the analysis chain that is defined in your custom analyzer.